# Map to /mnt/external_drive from windows

Tags: samba

OK so I followed [this guide](https://eltechs.com/raspberry-pi-nas-guide/) on how to prepare a file path on my pi for network sharing. I changed it up a bit since I want to map to an external hard drive which is connected to my pi via a powered USB hub. I mounted the drive in /mnt/Toshiba_1TB/

However, now the guide is telling me to map to the drive on the pi in the following way:

pi-ip\INTERNAL

This is because in the guide you are mapping to a folder in the /home/pi path. But how do I tell windows to map the network drive to /mnt/Toshiba_1TB if the default path is (I assume) /home/pi/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it on the Pi in the /etc/samba/smb.conf file, so following the guide instead of

path = /home/pi/INTERNAL

use

path = /mnt/Toshiba_1TB

and map the drive in windows exactly the same as the guide