# Mounted external drive not accessible via windows

Tags: samba

OK So I have tried to set up a network drive:

Here is what I appended to the /etc/samba/smb.conf file

```
[EXTERNAL]
comment = Toshiba 1TB Drive
browseable = yes
path = /EXT_TOSH_1TB
writeable = Yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
browseable = Yes
public = yes
```

When I run `sudo lsblk -o UUID,NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,MODEL` I get:

```
UUID                                 NAME        FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT    LABEL  MODEL
                                     sda                931.5G                      2105
0826237926236742                     └─sda1      ntfs   931.5G /EXT_TOSH_1TB
                                     mmcblk0             14.7G
0298-4814                            ├─mmcblk0p1 vfat    41.5M /boot         boot
d4f0fd64-ad9d-4cfd-aa76-8d3541fbf008 └─mmcblk0p2 ext4    14.7G /             rootfs
```

I have restarted the samba server using `sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart`

Then I try to map to the drive using windows' map drive function:

```
192.168.1.67/EXT_TOSH_1TB
```

And then I get an error that the drive can't be found. Trying to access the folder using `cd EXT_TOSH_1TB` I get:

```
-bash: cd: EXT_TOSH_1TB/: Permission denied
```

Doing `sudo su`, `cd EXT_TOSH_1TB` gets me in, but when I try to create a folder I get:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘dd’: Read-only file system
```

After that, if I try to remount, using `sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1 /EXT_TOSH_1TB` I get:

```
mount: cannot remount dev/sda1 read-write, is write-protected
```

Does anyone know how I can:

a) Get my drive to be mounted read-write?

b) Get my drive found by windows when mapping a network drive?

PS - As a little extra; The drive also doesn't show up under "Network" in Windows either. If that helps figure out what's going on.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/78456/map-to-mnt-external-drive-from-windows

Comment: That's also my question, but the drive still does not show up in Windows. That's why I asked this question with the knowledge of the previous question in the hope that someone could shed more light on this. Pointing me to myself won't help :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution to your (b) ...

After a specific Windows Update, MS systems (esp Win10) will not allow the use of the SMBv1 protocol - security issues. They now "require" SMBv2. Therefore, Windows will not see the share, etc

To resolve add the following line in the share definition

```
protocol = smb2
```

Which should force the use of SMBv2

However, I still have the issue of the connected drive being read-only and haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Do you ask for a solution about the read/write problem? I think you will not get an answer to an answer. You should ask a new question. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.